# ToString(format) which ones are available in the micro framework

Tags: c#, .net-micro-framework, .net-gadgeteer

I just want to make sure that at a minimum my digits are displaying with 2. So 1 should display as 01.

I need this for time display XX:XX.XX

Formats I have tried but all of them seem to throw an error
"D2",
"D5",
"00" (Custom )

```
        display_T35.SimpleGraphics.DisplayText(
            String.Concat(timeParts.Minutes.ToString(), 
                          ":",
                          timeParts.Seconds.ToString(),
                          ".",
                          timeParts.Milliseconds.ToString()),
            font,
            color,
            TimerCoordinates.X,
            TimerCoordinates.Y
            );
```

Minutes, Seconds and Milliseconds are uint.

I just get a Exception for any of them:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occured in mscorlib

I am not sure if the format string is supported but it is showing it to me through intellisense.

Thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be specific in your question. You do not show us the type of `timeParts`. I'm going to assume that the `Minutes`, `Seconds`, and `Milliseconds` properties are Int32.

The documentation for the .Net Micro Framework is available on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc533014.aspx). If you drill down into the methods for [System.Int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc506840.aspx) you will see a very limited version of the formats the ToString() method accepts.

There seems to be an open source project, [.Net Micro Framework Common Extensions](http://netmfcommonext.codeplex.com/), which implements some of the string manipulation features of the full .Net framework. They might have what you need, or you could write your own specific formatter.

Comment: Thanks yeah I saw the extensions before forgot about them. Let me try it out.